# Full Screen UIScrollView not working Correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have an application like the photos app where the main view is a `UIScrollView` which takes up the full size of the screen. Also, like the photos app, when the user taps the screen there are translucent navigation, status, and tool bars which reappear / disappear.

I am having a problem setting the `UIViewControllers` main view as a `UIScrollView` and having it take up the full length of the screen. The problem is that when the navigation and status bars are shown, the `UIScrollView` gets pushed down by the height of the navigation and status bars (it doesn't go underneath them like it's suppose to). When the user taps the screen and the navigation / status bars disappear, then it resets itself to take up the full length of the screen like it's suppose to.

A simple work around of setting the main view as a `UIView` and attaching a `UIScrollView` on top of it works. However, I'd like to try and get this to work without any workarounds (ie adjusting the `UIScrollViews contentInset`, etc) because in theory it should work.

Below is the code I'm implementing:

```
- (void)loadView
{

    self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    self.view = scrollView;
    [scrollView release];

}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated: NO];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = YES;

    [self startTimer];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated: NO];

    [self cancelTimer];
}
```

UPDATE: I've noticed it's the `contentOffset` and `contentInset` that are changing, not the `scrollViews` frame. When the bars have disappeared and the `UIScrollView` is the full size of the screen (as it should be), the `contentOffset` and `contentInset` are as follows:

```
Content Offset: {0, -20}
Content Inset: {20, 0, 44, 0}
```

When the bars are visible and the `UIScrollView` is pushed down, the `contentOffset` and `contentInset` are as follows:

```
Content Offset: {0, -64}
Content Inset: {64, 0, 44, 0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke with DTS about this and they said this is the designed behavior and recommended to attach the `UIScrollView` to a parent `UIView`.

Comment: Bless you! I just tore my hair out on this.

Answer (score 5):

I solved a similar issue on iOS7 after reading Apple's UI Transition Guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

It turns out `UIViewController` has a `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` boolean property.
Default is true, disabling this made my `UIScrollView` fill up the entire window, instead of being pushed down.

Answer (score -1):

Try be setting:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, -44.f, 320.f 480.f);
```

It may not size as you wish, but you can adjust it...

Comment: I updated, it's the contentOffset that's changing not the frame. I know I can adjust the contentOffset to make up for this, but trying to find a better solution.

Comment: I don't think there's a better solution than to overwrite some values the navigation controller automatically changes. It would be either the frame or the content offset. You can have a normal UIView for the self.view, then add the UIScrollView as subview and play around with the frame or the contentOffset, but there isn't a generic property like `resizeMyControllersMainView` to set it to `NO`...